# Ways to get sum of two lowest positive integers (JS debugging failure)

Tags: javascript

I was doing this [Codewar challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/558fc85d8fd1938afb000014/train/javascript) of getting sum of two smallest integer.

so I was trying to solve with this:

```
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {  
    const m = numbers.sort( (a, b) => a - b )[2];   
    const a = numbers.filter(v => v < numbers.sort( (a, b) => a - b )[2]);
    const b = a.reduce( (acc, n) => acc + n);
    return b
};
```

It works, and later on I feel that `const m` is redundant, so I commented the whole `const m` line and then it doesn't work now, by "doesn't work" I mean it's giving incorrect outcome, not typeErrors.

My question is, how is that possible??

I mean on `const a` I literally rewrote what `const m` was referring to.

How is deleting something that is repeated affects the outcome?

Thanks in advance, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Did you delete the entire line, or just `const m`?

Comment: actually I commented the line. thanks for clarification!

Comment: I tried your code in online js compiler without const m and it works fine.

Comment: Ah. I see! wow that's a quick one. Thank you so much

Comment: @OgünBirinci I've tried my original code in codewar in-browser editor and also VScode, both doesn't work. Can you show me which online js compiler you were using?

Comment: @chiukaun https://www.programiz.com/javascript/online-compiler/

Comment: @OgünBirinci if you run the code with ```const m``` it works fine. My question is if you commented out the ```const m``` line it gives incorrect answer. I get the same result on the online compiler as in VScode. 
But as @evolutionxbox said in previous comment, I should sort the array first and filter it later. If I comment out the ```const m``` line the array would be un-sorted when filter.

Comment: This is an extremely impractical way of achieving this, you are doing too much (filtering, sorting, reducing), you could simply replace it with a single loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, it is because the function `Array.prototype.sort` in javascript modifies the actual contents of the same instance of the array as well as returns the reference to the same array, In other words, it does not return a new array with the modified contents, it modifies the same array. That's why it doesn't work when you remove the line :

```js
const m = numbers.sort( (a, b) => a - b )[2];
```

But, why doesn't it work when you tried to put the same logic with  the next line of code?

```
const a = numbers.filter(v => v < numbers.sort( (a, b) => a - b )[2]);
```

The issue happens when the smallest value of the array is at an index larger than 2, for example:

```
[ 15, 28, 4, 2, 43 ]
```

when we try to execute the code on this array, lets take it a step by step to catch where it gets wrong.

```js
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {  
    const a = numbers.filter(v => v < numbers.sort( (a, b) => a - b )[2]);
    const b = a.reduce( (acc, n) => acc + n);
    return b
};
const arr = [ 15, 28, 4, 2, 43 ]
const result = sumTwoSmallestNumbers(arr)
console.log(result)
```

When executing the previous code, the first thing the function will do is the filtering.
It will iterate through the elements of the array:

- Starting from index **0** => arr[0] = 15

  > Testing the condition: `15 < numbers.sort( (a, b) => a - b )[2]` => (15 < 15) => **false**

> **Notice!** as I explained earlier, that the function sort will change the actual array rather than generating a new one, that means that when attempting to test the condition the first time, the array will be sorted, which means that if it is not already sorted, the order of its elements will defiantly change, which is a bad thing considering that the change happened during an ongoing loop through the arrays elements.

Before continuing the iteration of `filter`, let's make it clear that the new order of the array after the sorting has been executed when attempting to check the condition is as follows:

```
[ 2, 4, 15, 28, 43 ]
```

- Index **1** => arr[1] = 4

  > Testing the condition: `4 < numbers.sort( (a, b) => a - b )[2]` => (4 < 15) => **true**
- Index **2** => arr[2] = 15

  > Testing the condition: `15 < numbers.sort( (a, b) => a - b )[2]` => (15 < 15) => **false**
- ... The rest of the elements

### Conclusion

As you can notice, the value `15` has been checked twice, and the value `2`, has not been checked at all, which is because of the sudden change in the order of the array during the currently ongoing iteration of the `filter` method. Which has lead to placing the value of `2` in an already checked location, and the value of `15` into a location that has not been checked yet.

**! Notice** This is not an optimal solution to such a problem, it does too much work to get to the solution, (filtering, sorting, reducing), which are expensive operations to execute.
A better solution will be something like this, which involves a single loop through the elements of the array `O(n)`:

```js
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {  
  let lowest = Math.min(numbers[0], numbers[1]), 
      secondLowest = Math.max(numbers[0], numbers[1])
  for(let i = 2; i < numbers.length; i++){
    if(numbers[i] < lowest){
      secondLowest = lowest
      lowest = numbers[i]
    }else if(numbers[i] < secondLowest)
      secondLowest = numbers[i]
    else continue
  }
  return lowest + secondLowest
}
```

Comment: This is way beyond what I expected to learn, thank you @Abd Elbeltaji, I am deeply educated.